# Default value for linq select item if query didn't return anything

Tags: c#, linq

How to insert a default value to the returned collection if the `where` condition returns no results?

```
from i in data.collection
where i.Type == type
select i.Count
```

Comment: Why do you need a default item? An empty collection makes sense here.

Comment: i need to get '0' for every returned empty result

Comment: I have to agree with Rawling... a sequence of zero counts would be the obvious candidate here, unless Type makes it unique in some way

Comment: there **are** no results... so... zero zeros...? that would be: an empty sequence / collection

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the [`Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) method to do this.

Example (in method syntax because it IMHO is less awkward):

```
data.collection.Where(i => i.Type == type)
               .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultObject)
               .Select(i => i.Count);
```

Answer (score 9):

There's **[DefaultIfEmpty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx)** method.

In the method syntax, you can use it like this:

```
data.Collection
    .Where(i => i.Type == type)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(yourDefaultValue)
    .Select(i => i.Count);
```

If the `Where` filter returns no items, a one-item enumerable with `yourDefaultValue` is used as an input for the `Select` projection.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx).

```
var itemCounts = from i in data.collection
                 where i.Type == type
                 select i.Count;

var itemCountsOrMinusOne = itemCounts.DefaultIfEmpty(-1);
```

The first will give you the item counts, or an `IEnumerable` that returns no elements.

The second will then give you the item counts, or an `IEnuemrable` that just returns `-1`.